# How to prevent an addon installer from installation when main application is missing?

Tags: install4j

Today I have a question about the addon installation medium. We have to create an installer which installs some tools to extend the main application. Therefore I created a project and configured it as an addon installer. Therefore I set the application ID from the main application to the addon configuration. Then I expected that the installer checks whether the main app is installed or not. I also avoid to bundle the jre so the installer should use the jre from the main application. When I try to install the addons the installer ask for a suitable jre and then starts to install the component. I expected an error message and the installation to be aborted. Maybe I missed some configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call

```
ApplicationRegistry.checkApplicationId(context.getInstallationDirectory())
```

in a "Run script" action in add-on installer to check whether a main installer installation has been found. If the above returns false, you can return false from the script, set the "Failure strategy" property to "Quit on failure" and the "Error message" property to the error message that you wish to display.